# Set current location to match the Drive letter same as the running script's drive

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, how to dynamically read the Drive (letter) where running Script resides then set that Drive as current location so that:

1. all relative paths written in the script would use (and create files/folder-structure) in that drive, also,
2. after script-execution finishes, the PS-Command-Prompt would also show that Drive (where the running script resides):

For example, before execution, if the current location is C: drive, i.e. the PowerShell command prompt is showing "C:\" and my script resides in "D:\ps_scripts\test.ps1", all relative paths in the script should use (and create files/folder) in the D: drive.

Basically I'm developing an installer-script that should install the app in the Drive where the script is stored (i.e. it has to be "Relative" as opposed to "Absolute/Fixed" drive).

TIA

Comment: Your title is misleading, when running a script there is no prompt, you are referring to the current location.

Comment: Nope, there always a "Current-Drive" behind the scene (you're right that it won't be visible whilst execution, but) for example, if you want to (force) create a file into a path without the drive letter i.e. path starting with the root e.g. \myDir\ you will see your file will get created in the Drive that was visible before you started the execution, so if your PS-cmd-prompt was showing "PS Z:\test\", the file will be created within Z:\myDir>. If it was "PS C:\Windows>, the file will be created in C:\myDir\. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you run a script with a path on a different drive that doesn't change the current location. `Get-PSDrive | ? CurrentLocation` or `Get-Location` will tell you where your current location is.

Comment: Agree, I needed to set location of the Drive only (omitting the rest of the path), I have updated the question & title.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote following script which reads the drive-letter (such as `C:` drive) where currently running script resides, then sets current location (matching the same drive):

```
Write-host ('$PSScriptRoot: ' + $PSScriptRoot)    #Checking full path of own running script.
$drive = ((Get-Item $PSScriptRoot).PSDrive.Name)  #Getting drive letter of running script.
Set-Location -Path "$($drive):\"                  #Setting Disk-Drive on PS-Cmd-Prompt.
```

Note: I was getting error at the last line, because I had not enclosed the `$drive` variable within `$()`, which ***evaluates the expression***, as soon I did this, Voila!!!

Hope this helps others.